# I want start slideshow onClick DIV ID event beside ready function call

Tags: jquery, xml, slideshow

I want to start jquery slide show on click, using xml file, please anyone can help how i can convert this ready function call into onclick, so any div start running slide show,

as In many examples on internet which i found they are using On Html page slideshow is  auto start 
as under given function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "simplegallery_files/sites.xml",
        //xml file
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var count = 0; //counter
            $(xml).find('site').each(function () {
                var url = $(this).find('url').text(); //url
                var target = $(this).find('target').text(); //_blank, _new
                var imageURL = $(this).find('imageURL').text(); //location of the image
                var alt = $(this).find('alt').text(); //alternate text of the image
                //append to array
                myArray[parseInt(count)] = new Array(imageURL, url, target, alt);
                count++;
            });
```

I hope you will help me in this issue, i am stuck since one week,

Just what i need to do is to onClick call one DIV ID start slideshow,

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mm not clear , but i think you have to call your function inside the click function

```
$.ready(function(){

   $('#button').click(function(){

     //your code should be here ..........................

   });


});
```

so it will work for the click of the button , not when document is ready

Comment: But i have another ready function which is running already, it will will be colliding?? for example in template Header one ready call is already running, if i will call inside template for one page it will be colide this with previous ready function,although its calling on click function

Comment: mmmmmmmmmmmmm, why don 't you add the click function to your existing document.ready ? you dont need to write click function in a separate document.ready .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(#your_button).click(function() {
```

just exchange the first line with the above code. when the element of id "your_button" is clicked, your slideshow will be initialized.